# Cambiar hora a UTC

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, time

Tengo una duda creo que sencilla:
Tengo una hora leída en un archivo y quiera cambiarla a formato UTC.

Por ejemplo:

```
#esto es lo que tengo importado:
import datetime ,time
from pytz import timezone 

def cambio_fecha_hora_utc():
    fecha = 20180613
    hora = 17
    fecha_hora = fecha + hora

    tz = timezone("Europe/Madrid")  # obtengo la hora de Madrid que es donde estoy
    #lo que me gustaría es que me devolviera 
    fecha_hora_utc = #la fecha y la hora  ya en el formato utc
```

Saludos y gracia

Answer (score 2):

Convierte tu cadena a `datetime` primero para poder aplicar el método [`localize`](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/index.html?highlight=localize)  para añadirle información de la zona horario. Hecho esto solo necesitas usar  el método `astimezone` para realizar la conversión a cualquier zona horaria soportada:

```
import datetime
import pytz



def cambio_fecha_hora_utc(fecha):
    timezone = pytz.timezone("Europe/Madrid")
    fecha_local = timezone.localize(fecha, is_dst=None)
    fecha_utc = fecha_local.astimezone(pytz.utc)
    return fecha_utc


# Ejemplo
fecha = "20180613"
hora = "17"
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(fecha + hora, "%Y%m%d%H")
df_utc = cambio_fecha_hora_utc(dt)
print df_utc
#2018-06-13 15:00:00+00:00
```

La salida es un objeto `datetime.datetime`:

> ```
> >>> dt_utc
> datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 13, 15, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)
> ```